# Command not works in subprocess or os.popen but works in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, shell, command

I've tried lots of methods to run my shell script but none of these works from python3 script. The command is very simple and works in terminal without problem. Here's what I've tried without sucsess:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

dat = os.popen('sh commonBash.sh').read()
print(dat)
if "no" in dat:
    print('Not found')
    status = 'Install'
else:
    print('Found')
    status = 'Remove'
```

When I run in terminal the output is correct and working, but when I try to run in python script it won't work. 
Here's the shell script:

```
name="libreoffice" && dpkg-query -W $name && echo "$name"
```

The output of the python script is here:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libreoffice   # Here the $name is correct
                                                     # This is $name, which is an empty newline
Found                                                # I don't know why, but the output is found
```

However when I run the actual program, the output of the same part is somehow different. Here it is:

```
           # Empty lines for print(dat) and echo "$name" also
           # Why?
Found      # And the result is still Found...
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

In the form that you provide it evidently  complains about undefined names.
But when prepended with 
import os, subprocess
it prints "test" twice, as expected

Comment: I didn't get any error message. The value of `name` is nothing. The output is one empty line.

Comment: Really weird. I 've tried this on two system (MacOS and FreeBSD) and on both it prints test twice (or three times if I print dat variable).
Are your sure that value of shell variable $name is empty. Try    name=test && echo "name = $name" in your commonBash.sh
I'd rather suspect some problems with getting stdout of shell script.

P. S. I use python3 not wxpython.

Comment: On linux Mint (ubuntu 18.04) all 3 options work as expected.

Comment: It's strange... I've updated the answer, to give more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now it works with these changes:

Here's the shell script (commonBash.sh):

```
name=libreoffice
dat=$(dpkg-query -W $name)
echo "Checking for "$name": "
echo "$dat"
if [ "" == "$dat" ]; then
    echo "No "$name". Setting up "$name"..."
else
    echo $name" is installed already."
fi
```

Here's the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

dat = os.popen('bash commonBash.sh').read()
print(dat)
if "No" in str(dat):
    print('Not found')
    status = 'Install'
else:
    print('Found')
    status = 'Remove'
```

And here's the output (now it's correct):

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libreoffice
Checking for libreoffice: 

No libreoffice. Setting up libreoffice...

Not found
```